# Changing directories for the makefile in xScreenSaver

Tags: linux, makefile, screensaver

I am trying to build an xsreensaver module using the makefile. I downloaded the source from http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/, and read the hacking readme.

As my screensaver involves opengl and reading of images, I'm trying to compile the 'photopile' screensaver.

I've run the following

```
$ cd xscreensaver-5.29
$ cd hacks
$ cd glx
$ make photopile
```

After running I get the following output errors

```
cc     photopile.c   -o photopile
photopile.c:38:23: fatal error: xlockmore.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
make: *** [photopile] Error 1
```

The referenced file is in the "hacks" root folder rather than the "glx" folder. I realize it would be simple enough to just copy that needed file to "glx", but the "xlockmore.h" file is not the only file that its trying to find that is not in the current directory.

It is also looking for "yarandom.h" in the "../../utils" folder.

I'm assuming the makefile was made correctly, and that I am doing something wrong with regards to calling the

```
make photopile
```

option from within the "glx" folder.

I'm still learning makefiles and would rather not modify it (or the directory structure by copying header files) anymore than the directions say to.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you run the `./configure` script from the main `xscreensaver-5.29` directory?

Comment: That did it. Unfortunately its giving the following errors: gcc: error: ../screenhack.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: ../fps.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: ../../utils/grabclient.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [photopile] Error 1 which as far as I can tell, all the object files are located in the GLX folder. Is this possibly because I ran the "make" before I ran the "./configure"

Comment: You probably need to run `make` from the `hacks` directory first to create the main hack object files. You might be able to make just the ones that `gcc` error listed but you'd have to do that by hand I believe. It is probably easier just to run `make` and let it do its thing (though that will obviously compile more stuff).

Comment: Just for the record this is one of the main arguments used in the 'Recursive make considered harmful' paper. The fact that this didn't just work from the sub-directory.